# C# json deserialize object

Tags: c#, json

I am new with C#, and so I don't know too much about it. I want to deserialize json object, but I am having some issues.

Thi is json object:

```
var json  = "[{

  "idSite":"1",
  "visitorId":"a393fed00271f588",
  "actionDetails":[{
     "type":"action",
      "url":"http:\/\/mysite.info\/test-24\/",
      "customVariables":{
                  "1":{
                       "customVariablePageName1":"URL",
                       "customVariablePageValue1":"http:\/\/mysite.info\/p"
                       }
                   },
      "timeSpent":"78",
   }] 

}]";
```

And I am trying to deserialize it on this way:

```
var visits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VisitorDetails[]>(json);

public class VisitorDetails
{
    public string idSite { get; set; }

    public string visitorId { get; set; }

    public List<ActionDetail> actionDetails { get; set; }
}


public class ActionDetail
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public string url { get; set; }

    public string timeSpent { get; set; }

    public object customVariables { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is fine, except "customVariables" in "ActionDetails" it just set it to object with one value as string:

```
{
 "1":{
     "customVariablePageName1":"URL",
     "customVariablePageValue1":"http:\/\/mysite.info\/p"
     }
}
```

It doesn't deserialize it at all.

I need this deserialize so I can say:

```
foreach (var visit in Model.PiwikInfo)
{
   @foreach (var action in visit.actionDetails)
   {
      @if (action.customVariables != null && action.customVariables.Any())
      {
        foreach (var cv in visit.customVariables.Where(cv => cv.HasProperty("customVariablePageName1")))
        {
         <span>URL: @cv.GetProperty("customVariablePageValue1")</span>
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this happens, because you have specified that the `customVariables` member is of type `System.Object`. So deserialization will result in assigning it the string value.

So lets try to mold it into a shape that better resembles the input JSON structure and your specific use of the deserialization result, in two steps, by changing the type declaration of the `customVariables` member variable, and inspecting its deserialized content after each change.

1. Make it a **dictionary**:

   ```
   public Dictionary<string, object> customVariables { get; set; }
   ```

   This will result in a dictionary that contains a single element with the key `"1"` and a single string value:

   ```
   {
       "customVariablePageName1": "URL",
       "customVariablePageValue1": "http://mysite.info/p"
   }
   ```
2. Make it a **dictionary of dictionaries:**

   ```
   public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> customVariables { get; set; }
   ```

   And print its deserialized ouput like this:

   ```
   var visits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VisitorDetails[]>(json_string);

   foreach (var visit in visits)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Visitor: {0}", visit.visitorId);
       foreach (var detail in visit.actionDetails)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("  Action: {0}", detail.type);
           foreach (var cv in detail.customVariables.Where(x => x.Value.ContainsKey("customVariablePageName1")))
           {
               Console.WriteLine("    Custom variable #{0}", cv.Key);
               Console.WriteLine("    Value: {0}", cv.Value["customVariablePageValue1"]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Which resembles your view's `foreach`, and will produce the following output:

   ```
   Visitor: a393fed00271f588
     Action: action
       Custom variable #1
       Value: http://mysite.info/p
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't still comment I will have to post this as an answer. have you tried using the built in function of C#?
[See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

Also, from what I gather, on the Documentation of that method it converts it converts the json into a system object.

Also, from the looks of it it seems like the `customVariables` segment is either an array or a broken object. I say that because it is missing the square brackets like in the previous declarations, making it look like:

```
...
"customVariables":[{
                  "1":[{
                       "customVariablePageName1":"URL",
                       "customVariablePageValue1":"http:\/\/mysite.info\/p"
                       }]
                   }],
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot change the json, I am getting it as response from one API. Also didn't try the built in function, because for some reason I need to get work on this way.

Answer (score 0):

try this structure

```
    public class T1
{
    public string customVariablePageName1 { get; set; }
    public string customVariablePageValue1 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomVariables
{
    public T1 t1 { get; set; }
}

public class ActionDetail
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public CustomVariables customVariables { get; set; }
    public string timeSpent { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string idSite { get; set; }
    public string visitorId { get; set; }
    public List<ActionDetail> actionDetails { get; set; }
}
```